# Converting .CSV file to .XLS using VB.net

Tags: vb.net, csv, excel-2007, xls

I am trying to convert a .csv to .xls using vb.net but I am having trouble finding something that works. I know how to convert an .xls to .csv is it similar to this? Here is the code I have so far and this is the error I recieve:

"External table is not in the expected format."

```
Public Sub ConvertCSV(ByVal lvFileName As String, ByVal lvFileNameNoExt As String)

Dim DA As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter

Dim DS As New DataSet

Dim objStreamWriter As StreamWriter

Dim objconn As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\GD Test\Test.csv;Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;")


    ObjConn.Open()

    Dim objcmd As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand("Select * from [AutoBatchPrintBypass.RPT$]", objconn)

    objcmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text


    objStreamWriter = New StreamWriter(gvDipDir & gvClientCode & ".XLS")


    objconn.Close()

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

When reading the CSV file, your telling the Jet Engine that its an excel file with this part of the connection string `Extended Properties=Excel 8.0`. Try changing that part of the connection string to this `Extended Properties='text;HDR=Yes;FMT=Delimited(,)'`. I got that from [this page](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/27802/Using-OleDb-to-Import-Text-Files-tab-CSV-custom).

As for writing the file, there are a few things you can do, here is a similiar SO question,

[Create Excel (.XLS and .XLSX) file from C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151005/create-excel-xls-and-xlsx-file-from-c-sharp)